# What's wrong with passing generics map

Tags: java, generics, collections

i have followed call up in a constructor of class Car:

```
public Car(Map<String, ? extends List<? extends WingMirror>> wingMirrorMap) {
    doSomething(wingMirrorMap); // Here i have error
}

private static <L extends List<M>, M extends WingMirror<T>, T> Map<String, L> doSomething (Map<String, L> wingMirrorMap) {
    // Do something with wingMirrorMap
}
```

By passing the argument wingMirrorMap i have followed Error:

`The method doSomething(Map<String,L>) in the type Car is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,capture#2-of ? extends List<? extends WingMirror>>)`

Why does it not work. I don't see any thing which could be wrong with the method call.

Comment: When did `Color` become a parameterized type?

Comment: Here is definition of Color Class `public class Color<T> extends SuperColor<T> {}`

Comment: Ah, so it's not `java.awt.Color` then.  Part of your problem might be that one `Color` is parameterized and the other is not.

Comment: Don't name your types the same as well-known `java.*` types.

Comment: It's just a example

Comment: Obviously your naming is causing confusion here. So it doesn't matter if it is an example, does it.

Comment: Okey just changed the code for avoiding confusion. `Color` is now `WingMirror`

Comment: now the comments are causing confusion, change back to Color !

Comment: @LewBloch no harm in clashing with `java.awt` types if you have no intention of every going anywhere near AWT.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the `List<? extends WingMirror>` declaration.

Your `doSomething` method is declared to only take one sub type of `WingMirror`by having `M extends WingMirror<T>` in its signature. But car constructor is trying to pass list that is allowed to have different sub types of `WingMirror`.

For example if you have two sub types of `WingMirror` as `SubWingMirror1` and `SubWingMirror2`. The `doSomething` will only take list that has only `SubWingMirror1` or `SubWingMirror2` but not both. But `List<? extends WingMirror>` can have mix of either sub types.